# Django finding entries with NO ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-models

I ve got the Following models:

```
class M1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class M2(models.Model):
    models.ManyToManyField(M1, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I'd like to get all the M1 Objects which do not have a category. I have no clue, how to start, any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit weird but the basic concept is that there will be an automatic reverse relationship on M1 called `m2` and also there is a query filter called [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull) which when applied to M2M relationships means that there is no link between the two models.

```
orphans = M1.objects.filter(m2_isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it. For any reason, in my django version i only got 'm2' instead of 'm2_set'